# Использование python скрипта в DLL

Tags: c++, python, dll

Есть необходимость задействовать python скрипт в своих DLL. Причем желательно чтобы эта DLL, не пыталась тащить питоновские библиотеки и DLL. Как например делает PyInstaller, собирая все необходимое в единственный EXE.

Каким способом можно такое реализовать?

Одно из возможных решений это вызов скриптов непосредственно из C++ кода, но получится ли тогда упаковать все необходимые файлы в DLL?

### UPD1:

На данный момент мне удалось из C++ кода выполнить скрипт и получить из него результат. Сейчас мне необходимо собрать все зависимости питона и упаковать в одну DLL, чтобы получить stand alone DLL которая сможет работать без других файлов (относительно питона)

Я скомпилировал библиотеку питона, ее я смогу(?) подключить к проекту так, что бы она "слилась" с DLL на выходе, но как подцепить статические библиотеки питона из папки Lib, которые тоже необходимы для скрипта? 
На попытки перенести папку Lib и добавить sys.path.insert(0, "%путь до папки%") получаю "No module named site"

### UPD2:

Свалил все нужные модули в папку с DLL, работает, осталось упаковать все в один DLL.

Итого имею:
   python27.lib/python27.dll
   Куча python модулей
   Python скрипт
   Исходный C++ код

Все это необходимо склеить в одну DLL, как это можно сделать?

### UPD3:

Ладно, предположим что предыдущая задача не выполнима легким путем, попробую поставить новую: обойтись в EXE + DLL.

Python скрипт можно засунуть в C++ код в виде строки, но как можно python модули сложить в python27.dll?

Comment: по всей видимости, нужно статические библиотеки питона прилинковать к своему проекту.

Comment: embedded python, думаю, вам поможет. Правда я не уверен что оно нормально будет работать из DLL.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: Действительно, поясните что вы хотите получить. Интерпритатор питона внутри процесса? Вам нельзя больше одной DLL поставлять?

Comment: На данный момент мне удалось из C++ кода выполнить скрипт и получить из него результат. Сейчас мне необходимо собрать все зависимости питона и упаковать в одну DLL, получить stand alone DLL которая сможет работать без других файлов (относительно питона)